# Testing @1x view in simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, ios10

Is it still possible to test an @1x view app in simulator, since most iOS devices doesn't support it. Also, I believe that no device will be supported with iOS 10.

Comment: iPad 2 and iPad mini support iOS 10 and use @1x images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **iPad 2** simulators are still available (at least for iOS 9.3).

They have a non retina resolution, so you can use them to run your app in a @1x environment. Even if your app is an iPhone app you can still use them to simulate an @1x iPhone (if your app is iPhone only).

Answer (score 1):

iOS 10 will support the iPad 2 and iPad mini, the two remaining devices which support @1x images (see the [Icon and Image Sizes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html) section of the HIG).

With a fresh install of Xcode 8 Beta and iOS 10 beta for these devices I was able to test @1x images.

Comment: The Downloads page on the Apple developer site does not have iOS 10b1 for the iPad 2 or the 1st gen iPad mini. Are you sure they are supported?

Comment: @rmaddy I'm at WWDC and just tested with some Apple equipment.

Comment: OK. Tell someone there that there is no iOS 10b1 download for the iPad2, iPad 3, or iPad Mini 1 assuming they really will be supported. And the 5th gen iPod touch.

Comment: @rmaddy, Ok.  I see them listed [here](http://www.apple.com/ios/ios10-preview/) but you are right, looks like downloads are not available for those devices.

Comment: Note that both the iPad 2 and the original iPad mini has now been removed from the list.